# Joomla 3 form validation

Tags: form, joomla-3.4, validations

Why the form validation does not work on Safari ?

I tried not to load the `JHTML::_(behavior.formvalidator)`

I load the fields from the XML file

```
<field 
    name="title" 
    type="text"
    label="COM_MYCOMP_LBL_TITLE"
    required="true"  
    class="form-control"
/>
```

With this result

```
<input id="jform_title" class="form-control required" type="text" aria-required="true" required="required" value="" name="jform[title]">
```

This result contains the attributes of validation
aria-required="true" required="required" that I would not use

How do I turn off html5fallback.js and use a different library of validation ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `required="required"` is standard HTML5 validation, - the html5fallback.js is just a polyfill for those browsers that do not support html5 validations.

To answer your question add `novalidate` to your `<form>` markup:

```
<form novalidate>
....
</form>
```

This turns off html5 validation.